# Converting cartesian double integral into polar integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Write down the integral

> $$\int_0^4 \int_x^ {4x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dydx$$

$(i)$ integration with respect to $\theta$ first and $r$ second.

Comment: Do you mean $$\int_0^4 \int_x^ {4x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dydx$$
?

Comment: I can do it with respect to $r$ first and then $\theta$ second but the other way around has completely confused me!

Comment: You need a different jacobian since the jacobian is $r$ when you proceed in the manner of $dr$ then $d\theta$

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what that means, would you be able to provide an answer?

Comment: round pegs into square holes? hmmm...

Comment: Any chance of an answer? It is one of the "odd" questions in a textbook haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to break up the polar integral into two parts: the red and green part.

[image]

In the red part,
$$
\theta\in\left[\pi/4,\tan^{-1}(4)\right]
$$
whereas in the green part
$$
\theta\in\left[\cos^{-1}(4/r),\tan^{-1}(4)\right]
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r
$$
Thus, the integral becomes
$$
\underbrace{\int_0^{4\sqrt2}\int_{\pi/4\vphantom{\left(4/r\right)}}^{\tan^{-1}(4)} r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r}_{\text{red part}}+\underbrace{\int_{4\sqrt2}^{4\sqrt{17}}\int_{\cos^{-1}(4/r)}^{\tan^{-1}(4)} r^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r}_{\text{green part}}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! However, how did you get $tan^{-1}(4)$? Also how did you know where to split the integral up, if this was a different question, what advice would you give? Thank you!

Comment: I see how you got the $tan$! However how did you get the bounds for $\theta$ for the green part?

Comment: @THISISIT453: draw the right triangle with base $4$ and hypotenuse $r$. The base angle is $\cos^{-1}(4/r)$.

Comment: How about for the green part?

Comment: @THISISIT453: that *is* for the green part.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, why do you have hypotenuse r? Where did that come from?

Comment: Look at the arc of radius $r$ in the green region. It goes from $x=4$, that is $\theta=\cos^{-1}(4/r)$, to $\theta=\tan^{-1}(4)$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for your help, it all make sense now!